# GNU find: regex to find a range of Unicode codepoints

Tags: regex, awk, sed, unicode, find

I'm looking for a way to find all files or directories which contain a specific range of characters in their name.

The characters I want to find are the [Unicode diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) in the range `\u0300` to `\u036f`.

If it were normal characters, I could just write `-regex '[a-x]'`. Using Perl, I can do

```
find ... | perl -CS -ne 'print if ( /[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]/ )'
```

Is something like this possible using one of the `-regextypte`s that is supported by GNU `find` ? My `find` reports that it would support these:

> `find -regextype help`
>
> ... valid types are 'findutils-default', 'awk',
>   'egrep', 'ed', 'emacs', 'gnu-awk', 'grep', 'posix-awk', 'posix-basic',
>   'posix-egrep', 'posix-extended', 'posix-minimal-basic', 'sed'.

**Update:** what I really want to find is not names with any accented characters, but only those which use the [NFD form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms): letter followed by the accent. Names where accented characters are already encoded in the NFC form, which is the default on Linux and Windows, should not be listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a unicode-encoded regular expression. If you use `bash`,

```
$ find . -regex $'.*[\u0300-\u036f].*'
./foo/foòbar
./foo/asd͊fgh
```

The `$'string'` syntax converts the string like a C compiler would. If you do not use `bash`, your shell probably won't support this kind of string literal. You could then resort to something like

```
$ find . -regex $(echo -e '.*[\u0300-\u036f].*')
```

The normal findutils-default regex type supports this, and in my tests with findutils 4.7.0, so did all the others.

Comment: Sounds great, but unfortunately doesn't quite work for me. With a UTF-8 locale, the accents land on `[` and `-`, and I get `failed to compile regular expression '.*[̀-ͯ].*': Invalid collation character`. With `LC_ALL="C"`, it lists all names with accented characters, whether they use the NFD form or the normal NFC form. As if find would convert everything to NFD before evaluating the regex and then back for printing it out?

Comment: Interesting. It works for me with `de_DE.utf8`. I suppose it could be something locale-related, but I suspect it's not that the locale is a utf8 locale. What locale are you using?

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work 2 years ago. But now it does in Ubuntu 20.04, with LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF8 or other UTF8 locales. Not with "C" or "POSIX", but that seems normal.

Answer (score 1):

Use either gawk in bytes mode, like gawk -b, or mawk1.3.4 or mawk1.9.9.6,

since U+0300 code  point is \314\200 in octal, and U+036F is \315\257, we know it'll take up all 64 combos of 314, and first 75% of 315. Then write it as

```
 find . \( -type f -or -type d \) | {mawk/mawk2/gawk -b -e} '/\314|\315[\200-\257]/'
```

octals are preferred over \x7F type notatoin since the hex one isn't posix-required. octals are guaranteed to work on all 3 variants of awk.